# Pandas groupby to get mean in a certain format

Tags: pandas, python-3.5

I have the following dataframe `df`:

Out[15]:

```
                     Run_299  Run_300      Month       Date       bkt
DateTime                                                            
2024-12-31 21:00:00  13       18           2024-12-01 2024-12-31  p
2024-12-31 21:00:00  11       12           2024-12-01 2024-12-31  p
2024-12-31 22:00:00  2         5           2024-12-01 2024-12-31  q
2024-12-31 23:00:00  113     118           2024-12-01 2023-11-30  p
2025-01-01 00:00:00  110     114           2025-01-01 2023-11-30  p
```

I am trying to get the following average calculations:

```
Date        bkt   mean
2024-12-31  p     13.5
2023-11-30  q     3.5
2023-11-30  p     113.75
```

Where:

```
13.5 = average(13, 18, 11, 12)
3.5 =average(2, 5)
113.75=average(113, 118, 110, 114)
```

I tried:

```
df.groupby(['Date', 'bkt']).mean()
```

But the average doesn't happen as expected. I still get the columns `Run_299` and `Run_300`

Edit:

I changed the `average` to show that I am trying to calculate mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `melt` before groupby

```
df_final = (df.melt(['Month','Date','bkt'], value_name='Run_mean')
              .groupby(['Date', 'bkt']).mean())    

Out[202]:
                Run_mean
Date       bkt
2023-11-30 p      113.75
2024-12-31 p       13.50
           q        3.50
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC using `stack` and `groupby`

```
new_df = (
    df.set_index(["Date", "bkt"])
    .filter(like="Run")
    .stack()
    .groupby(level=[0, 1])
    .mean()
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={0: "Run Mean"})
)
```

---

```
print(new_df)

       Date bkt  Run Mean
0 2023-11-30   p    113.75
1 2024-12-31   p     13.50
2 2024-12-31   q      3.50
```

Comment: Wouldn't set_index with Date and bkt remove duplicate rows even thought on the original index they are unique?